# Flutter Icon Animation

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter design. So I have a question about Icons Animations. I've created IconButton in flutter application with star:

```
IconButton(color: _isFavourite
           ? Theme.of(context).primaryColor
           : Colors.grey[600],
           onPressed: () => changeFavourites(),
           icon: Icon(Icons.star)),
```

When user clicks the button, star changes color. Just changes it, and nothing more. The question is: can I somehow make this changing color transition more interesting? Like more smooth or something like this
Maybe there is a package to create such a icons animations? 
Thanks

Comment: You just want to animate color or also the icon(shape)?

Comment: Just color. I want it to change smoothly

Comment: And also I wanna add something that will make button incredibly beautiful, but I'll ask it in another question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While this is about animating `Color`, you can use [`ColorTween`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/ColorTween-class.html)

```dart
class _ColoAnState extends State<ColoAn> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController controller;
  late Animation animation;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    controller = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200), //controll animation duration
      vsync: this,
    )..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });

    animation = ColorTween(
      begin: Colors.grey,
      end: Colors.red,
    ).animate(controller);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Icon(
          Icons.favorite,
          color: animation.value,
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {
        if (controller.value == 1)
          controller.reverse();
        else
          controller.forward();
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

More about [`AnimationController`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/AnimationController-class.html) and [`ColorTween`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/ColorTween-class.html)

Comment: If you have multiple animation, replace `SingleTickerProviderStateMixin `  with`TickerProviderStateMixin`

Comment: Good Explanation and perfect solution @Yeasin

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [AnimatedIcon](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AnimatedIcon-class.html) Widget

Answer (score 0):

Try out his article posted on medium about AnmiatedIcons.

https://medium.com/@pinkesh.earth/how-to-animate-icons-in-flutter-b96fe856a5b8

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).